# How to read data from RTF file & write it to ScrollableText at the time of installation?

Tags: rtf, installshield-2011, installscript-msi

I'm having InstallScript MSI project built in InstallShield. I''m having Custom License Dialog in my installer. I want to read data from license RTF file and write it to ScrollableText control using InstallScript. How can I achieve this?

Also Is there any way to set FileName of ScrollableText control at installation time using InstallScript?

At installation time, I tried to read all data from RTF file to LIST using InstallScript function `ListReadFromFile()` and tried to write that data to ScrollableText using function `CtrlSetMLEText()`. But ScrollableText is not showing all data of RTF file.

So can someone please suggest me any another way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScrollableText` control was truncating the data is because it can only show data up to specific character count (32xxx).
To solve this, I have changed the limit of `ScrollableText` before sending data to it. Using the following code we can set the character limit for the edit box.

```
// Get dialog handle
hDlg = CmdGetHwndDlg(SD_DLG_LICENSE_RTF);

// Get Control handle
hScrollControl = CtrlGetDlgItem(SD_DLG_LICENSE_RTF, hDlg, 301);

SendMessage(hScrollControl, EM_LIMITTEXT, 40000, 0);
```

Using `EM_LIMITTEXT` or `EM_EXLIMITTEXT`, we can set a limit for edit fields.
Here is a related article on [MSDN blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070111-02/?p=28443) for this scenario.